# Array push action, can i improve the code

Tags: javascript

I am using an Array push function to add elements to an array

```
var Oben = document.getElementById("Oben")
var Unten = document.getElementById("Unten")
if( Oben ) {
    objekte.push( Oben );
}
if( Unten ) {
    objekte.push( Unten );
}
```

Can i improve this coding style some how?

Comment: Looks okay. If you find yourself doing a lot of these things, maybe use something like jQuery.

Comment: First, use lower case: `oben`, not `Oben`. Second, use english: `above`, not `oben`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var Oben = document.getElementById("Oben");
var Unten = document.getElementById("Unten");

!Oben ||  objekte.push( Oben );
!Unten ||  objekte.push( Unten );
```

or

```
var Oben = document.getElementById("Oben");
var Unten = document.getElementById("Unten");

Oben &&  objekte.push( Oben );
Unten &&  objekte.push( Unten );
```

Comment: I recommend `Unten &&  objekte.push( Unten );` requires less stuff from the PC

Answer (score 2):

It's fine. But if you must:

```
function pushIfFound(list, id){
    var node = document.getElementById(id);
    if (node){
       list.push(node);
    }
}

pushIfFound(objekte, 'Oben');
pushIfFound(objekte, 'Unten');
```

Answer (score 0):

To example, so:

```
var Oben = document.getElementById("Oben"),
    Unten = document.getElementById("Unten");
```

Answer (score 0):

I probably wouldn't do this in real life as it's not the most intuitive for others to maintain but to do the comparison in one line:

```
var Oben = document.getElementById("Oben");
var Unten = document.getElementById("Unten");
objekte.push(Oben?Oben:Unten?Unten);
```